# How to find out the installation path to my browser?

Tags: package-management, paths

I am installing a proprietary CAD application (MEDUSA4 personal) and the installer wants to know the path to my web browser (as a prerequisite for online help). I have the default firefox installation and chromium, but I don't know the installation path for any of them, and couldn't find them among the usual suspects (/usr/bin, /usr/lib).

It would be nice if you could tell me the path to one of them, and even nicer if you can tell me how to find out the installation path to any package managed by apt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a console, do `which firefox`. This is my output, for instance:

```
user@PORTATIL:~$ which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
user@PORTATIL:~$ which google-chrome 
/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Answer (score 2):

Firefox is under /usr/bin/firefox but it's a symbolic link to /usr/lib/firefox-3.6.13/firefox.sh (please note that the version number may differ). I haven't installed gnome-chrome but it should be in /usr/bin like any other application.

Synaptic has an option to show installed files. Right-click in the package's name and select options and locate "Installed files" tab. Search for a line starting with /usr/bin or similar to see where the binary file (which is run when you open an application) is installed, as you can see some addtional files like icons and help files aren't installed to /usr/bin but probably under /usr/share.

Answer (score 0):

1. On the extremely-rare occasion that you get a choice, just install to the default. If there's no default, then /usr/bin should be alright.
2. Programs specify themselves where they install their bits to. Each part of the package needs to go into a different place so it can be found. You don't really need to know anything about this, but if you do, you can find where each part of the package has installed to by going to Synaptic, right-clicking on the package, going to Properties and then the Installed Files tab.